# Debug tool for creating and sending HTTP messages (e.g. Curl)

Tags: java, http, curl

I am developing a software which will be communicating with a server using HTTP (but it is not a web browser). Since the server part is not ready yet, I would like to debug my client software by sending HTTP messages to it. I know that I can send HTTP requests using Curl. But I am not sure if that is sufficient here.

I'm imagining an environment where I send a request from my application, check that it is correct using Wireshark and then reply to the request using some software. Using Curl, I think I would have open a listening port..?

Comment: Do you mean that your client software is "like" a webbrowser requesting data from the server part using get or post? 
As far as I know Curl is used as a client. But you would need the server part to find out, what your client app is doing.

Comment: No, it is not a webbrowser but it is using HTTP to communicate with a server. However, the server is implemented by someone-else and I want to debug my client my simulating a server, but without implementing a server. I just want to be able to send simple responses to it. Think I will go for the nodejs solution proposed by @PartlyCloudy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a simple node.js server for this. You can write your own HTTP server in a few lines of code an simulate various return codes, response headers or response entities easily: http://nodejs.org/

PS: There are proxies that simply print out the HTTP messages. This might be helpful for you too, because you don't have to deal with WireShark anymore just for HTTP-level logging.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with cURL. It is an http **client**, not a server.

The simplest way to do this is to actually implement a mock server application that just returns a static (i.e. hardcoded) message every time. You can do this using any server-side language you like (php, python, ruby, ...), or, you can even do it without a server side language, using just static files served by a webserver such as apache or nginx.

For example, if the server part (the API) would respond to `/articles.json` with something relevant (a JSON object containing some articles), you could put a file named `articles.json` that contains some hand-written data in your server's root. Then, your application would *think* it's calling an API when it's actually just downloading a static file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug addon of firefox browser to see content of HTTP request/response.
It does't require any server (but of course, if you dont have server which process requests from browser and send responses to browser, you 'll always see response "unable to connect").

If you still need to mock response, you can create simple server which is able to respond with mock responses, for example java servlet at tomcat server, with code like this:

```
public class MyMockServlet extends HttpServlet {
..
private String mockHeaders = "...";
private String mockResponse = "my response";
 public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response){
    setHeaderAndBodyInResponse(response);//your method
 }
}
```